# Multi-dimensional vector initialization

Tags: c++, stl, vector, initialization

I have following `std::vector` declaration:

`std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > m_input;`

I am initializing it as follows:

```
    m_input.resize (100);
    m_output.resize(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        m_input [i].resize(100);
        m_output[i].resize(100);
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j){
            m_input [i][j].resize(100);
            m_output[i][j].resize(100);
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve this via the *member initializer list*?

Comment: If your rows\cols\etc are equal in length id recommend to use a vector as `std::vector<int> m_input`; and initialize it as `m_input(100*100*100);`, then access elements as `m_input[x+y*100+z*100*100];`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`std::vector<T>` has a constructor that takes two arguments, a number of elements and an initial value. In your case, you want to initialize `m_input` with 100 copies of a `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` , so it'd be `: m_input(100, X)`. Now, that `X` in turn is a vector of 100 `std::vector<int>`, which in turn contains a hundred ints:

`: m_input(100, std::vector<std::vector<int> >(100, std::vector<int>(100, 0)))`

Answer (score 6):

```
my_class::my_class()
 : m_input(100, std::vector< std::vector<int> >(100, std::vector<int>(100) ))
{
}
```

That said, implementing a multi-dimensional field should be done by projecting into a one-dimensional one, as Viktor said in his comment to the question.

Comment: I love this constructor of vector :)

Comment: That should be `std::vector<int>`, surely?

Comment: sbi: `std::string name = "Viktor"; assert(name[2] == 'k');`

Comment: @Armen: if I could downvote a comment then I would downvote yours; sbi's most important message is in the text of this answer not in the code, re _should be done ..._

Comment: @FrankH. Yeah... so... er... why should that make me *not* love that constructor of vector? :)

Comment: @Viktor: It took me a while to figure out what you were talking about, but in the end I got it. I apologize.

Comment: @Armen: people in love tend to do crazy things, that's why. And just because certain things _can_ be expressed in a constructor initializer list doesn't mean _doing so_ is reasonable.

Comment: @sbi using single dimensional vector is good only until the size is not very high, isn't it? Say if I need to store 10000*10000 int then that would require 400 MB of contiguous memory which may not necessarily be available. So is it not better to use 2D vectors which use small chunks of memory? Just wanted your humble opinion...

Comment: @Cool_Coder: I don't have much of an opinion on that, as I have never worked with so much data. `:-/` What you say sounds reasonable enough, though. Off hand, and without any experience, I'd look into using `std::deque` instead. It allocates chunks of contiguous memory. But if your needs are serious, you might need to write your very own container, doing exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assert that your vector dimensions are going to be of a fixed length, then why not use `std::array`?

For example:

`std:array<std::array<std::array<int, 100>, 100>, 100>`

That way you can take advantage of all the memory being contiguously allocated (as hinted at by  [Viktor_Sehr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100724/viktor-sehr) in the comments), without the added implementation woes of accessing a 1-dimensional array in a 3-dimensional way.